# Getting a vue component styles to work with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm trying to get a basic modal working in my Rails 5 app but am having some trouble.

The modal I'm trying to incorporate is [very simple](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).

My code is as follows:

**javascript/packs/dashboard.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Modal from '../modal.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(document.getElementById('modal') !== null) {
    Vue.component('step-item', {
     template: '#modal-template'
    })
    const modal = new Vue({
      el: '#modal',
      components: { Modal },
      data: { showModal: false }
    })
  }
})
```

**modal.vue**

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style scoped>
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  float: right;
}

/*
 * The following styles are auto-applied to elements with
 * transition="modal" when their visibility is toggled
 * by Vue.js.
 *
 * You can easily play with the modal transition by editing
 * these styles.
 */

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

**_modal.html.erb**

```
<div id="modal">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">View pictures</button>
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
</div>
```

Clicking the button displays a template but it is unstyled. It's as if nothing between the `<style scoped>` tags is being read. Do I need a plugin in Rails to get the styles to load?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using webpacker you need to include the stylesheet_pack_tag in your layout.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: I had to name it the same as the **javascript_pack_tag**, i.e. `stylesheet_pack_tag 'application.css'`